# App is crashing when I add button on fragment

Tags: android, fragment

Firstly, I'd like to say that I'm a beginner, so please be patient with me!

I added a button in a Fragment to launch an `Activity`, but when I add a button in `fragment_home.xml` it does not crash, and when I add the action to MainActivity's Java it crashes at the start of launching.

I am sure I did something wrong, but what is it?

Should I add the buttons on `fragment_home.xml`?
because when I add it on content_main.xml it keeps showing on every Fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yartiplus.ri3aya_enligneservice">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Services"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Ask" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**XML File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_demander"
        android:layout_width="208dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="@string/title_info"

        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.522"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.665" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="212dp"
        android:layout_height="109dp"
        android:text="Yarti"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.527" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AlphaAnimation buttonClick = new AlphaAnimation(1F, 0.8F);

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow, R.id.nav_equipe, R.id.nav_admin, R.id.nav_close )
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        Button demander = findViewById(R.id.btn_demander);

        demander.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Ask.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_home) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            onVibration();
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Soon...!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            onVibration();
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_contact) {
            String[] to = {"myemail@gmail.com"};
            Intent sendemail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendemail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
            sendemail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.EXTRA_SUBJECT));
            sendemail.setType("message/rfc822");
            if (sendemail.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendemail, "Send Email"));
            }
            onVibration();
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_help) {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("help.txt");
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String line;
                StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = BR.readLine()) != null) {
                    msg.append(line + "\n");
                }
                AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                build.setTitle(R.string.title_help);
                build.setIcon(R.drawable.ri3aya);
                build.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(msg + ""));
                build.setNegativeButton(R.string.menu_close, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //Negative
                    }
                }).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }


        if (id == R.id.action_info)  {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Soon...!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            onVibration();
            return true;
       }

        if (id == R.id.action_close) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit?");
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("CLICK YES TO EXIT!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("YES",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    moveTaskToBack(true);
                                    onVibration();
                                    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                                    System.exit(1);
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("NOا", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            onVibration();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    public void  onVibration(){
        Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator)this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibe.vibrate(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you make button (btn_demander) in fragment xml. and called Main Activity. (Button demander = findViewById(R.id.btn_demander); <- this). it might be null point exception.

Comment: add your crash logs to figure out what went wrong

Comment: @s-t What do you suggest??? Thankx bro

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are getting the view of the button from the MainActivity.java .
Instead of doing that you can get that view from the frangment class itself.
Here you go...

**This is the Xml for your fragment**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SampleFrag">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And in your Fragment.java class

```
 public class SampleFrag extends Fragment {

    View v;
    Button btn;

    public SampleFrag() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        btn = v.findViewById(R.id.btn);
         v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false);

         btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 //do whatever you want...
             }
         });
         return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to creat ** empty public constructor?**  
and why `@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)` tells me: methods does not override method from its superclass ??

Comment: Whether you have implemented the above code or not. If it is the case what was the problem that you are getting because of that .